Data Recover from Encrypted LUKS Partition | Missing Files
I have been having some issue unmounting my encrypted drive recently. This lead to it being forceably removed instead of ejected.
It appears to have some done some damage to the drive as, although I can access some of the data within it, certain portions appear to be missing.
Are there any tools I can utilize to attempt to recover any lost data?
Thank you so much for any help. Some of the files on this drive are very important to me and I want to ensure I do everything possible in attempting to recover them. And in the future, utilize a more robust method of backing up data.

Please indicate whether the portions that are missing now were written during session which was terminated by forcible removal, or if they had previously been complete on the disk and have now become incomplete.

@AdminBee I didn't change any files during that session.
Old files, however, did go missing.


This lead to it being forceably removed instead of ejected.

That means that parts of what the file system wanted to write to finish the unmounting did not happen. That means that some data simply never made it onto the drive.
Can't rescue what's not there. Sorry.

And in the future, utilize a more robust method of backing up data.

I can't know for certain in your case, but in the vast majority of cases,

people either simply didn't wait long enough for data to be written to the external storage device, which happens to be slower than they expected, or
the storage device simply is defective and fails to read or write some regions

Assuming you did wait for loooong before removing the device, you should have checked dmesg for any output indicating that writing to the device failed. If there is any, then most likely, your drive is broken and needs to be repaired.

I didn't change any files during that session. Old files, however, did go missing.

Then my bet is definitely on a failing storage device! (though old files don't just randomly go missing, they are more likely to become unreadable. But chances are you have data corruption due to your failing hardware in the filesystem metadata, and that breaks things when directories are updated.)
